# Using Python to receive specific URLs from a webpage (Multireddit lists)

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, reddit

I'm trying to run some statistical analysis on topic-based multireddits. Rather than collecting each individual subreddit by hand, I have found websites that collect these subreddits ([Example](https://snoopsnoo.com/subreddits/travel/), [Example 2](https://www.reddit.com/user/baleman/m/gaming/)).

These sites unfortunately do not have the ability to download the list of subreddits into plaintext that can be used in a dictionary. Is there a specific method I could use to scrape these sites to only receive back the URL of each attached hyperlink on the webpage?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's my current code

Here's my current code, which runs, but returns every URL.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

url = "https://snoopsnoo.com/subreddits/travel/"

page = requests.get(url)

data = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):

    reddit = link.get('href')

    links.append(reddit)


df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['string_values'])

df.to_csv('travel.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will grab all of the titles.

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
#firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=firefox_options)
driver.get("https://snoopsnoo.com/subreddits/travel/")
for i in range(3):
    wds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
    for wd in wds:
        print(wd.text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/a').click
    print('next page')

driver.close()
```

Change `3` to **how many pages you want** in `for i in range(3):` Uncomment `firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')` to use headless mode

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is such a method. If you are using Python, a widely used library is Beautifulsoup. This library parses the HTML directly, so no webdriver is necessary or running a webbrowser in the background like with selenium. You can install it with: `pip install bs4`.

For your first example site:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Load the url
url = "https://snoopsnoo.com/subreddits/travel/"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
# Create the parser object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Find all panel headings
panels = soup.find_all(class_="panel-heading big")
# Find the <a>-elements and exctract the link
links = [elem.find('a')['href'] for elem in panels]
print(links)
```

Here I checked the contents of the page to locate the panel elements by class and then extracted the `<a>`-elements and its href-attribute.

Comment: Would there be a way to specifically filter by "/r/"?

I attached my current code up top.

Comment: You could add that you only include the link if it includes that string: `if '/r/' in reddit: links.append(reddit)`